# uploading file winForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I am developing a windows application and I want to add a browse button to upload file and once the user chooses file or files to be uploaded (only pdf files), I want to append them in a panel, and when clicking on any file it opens in adobe reader as these files are pdf.

Comment: okay good for you :) good luck

Comment: Is there a question here? Or is this just your to-do list for the day?

Comment: Upload or just load? And what is the actual question?

Comment: my question is how to add those files to a list ,,select a file and open it through,,,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The browse button click event should be like this,

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            Process.Start(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure about the later part of the question though. Do you want to load (open) the file or upload it? And what exactly do you want to add to the panel? A panel is simply a controls container.

Comment: thnx Devedra ,,,,after uploading the files i want to know how can i show these files in a list ,,so i can be able to select any file in that list and lets say i add another button "View Files" on i clicked on that button the file is opened in adobe reader

Comment: Use Process.Start(fileName) to 'View Files'. This method opens the file through its default process. You can add the fileName to the list after it has been uploaded and include the Process.Start method in the View button Click event handler.

Comment: Thanks Devendra D.Chavan so much for ur help

Comment: Why is there a foreach doesn't user only select 1 file?

Answer (score 3):

Windows is sufficient enough to understand which file types need to open with which program just need to open or start the file.

like

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("filepath.pdf")
```

window will open it as new pdf document and will be opened with the associated program like adobe reader, foxit reader, etc....